# pandas crosstab and normalising indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, crosstab

How do you normalize a pandas crosstab which has multiindex?

Suppose you have df like this:

```
# RANDOM DATA
np.random.seed(2)

Year = [2020,2019,2018,2017]*1000
col1 = ['A','B','C','D']*1000
col2 = np.random.randint(0,2,4000)
weight = np.random.randint(1,3,4000)

random.shuffle(Year)
random.shuffle(col1)
random.shuffle(col2)
random.shuffle(weight)

column_names = ['Year', 'weight', 'col1', 'col2']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

df['Year'] = Year
df['col1'] = col1
df['col2'] = col2
df['weight'] = weight
```

And now you do a crosstab out of that:

```
pd.crosstab(index=[df['Year']],
            columns=[df['col1'], df['col2']],
            values=df['weight'],
            aggfunc=sum)

col1         A                   B                   C                   D  \
col2         0         1         0         1         0         1         0   
Year                                                                         
2017  0.117962  0.128686  0.128016  0.130697  0.137399  0.122654  0.115282   
2018  0.116832  0.111551  0.120132  0.118152  0.138614  0.125413  0.131353   
2019  0.137584  0.126846  0.127517  0.108725  0.114765  0.138255  0.114765   
2020  0.116356  0.134309  0.113032  0.143617  0.121676  0.118351  0.121676   

col1            
col2         1  
Year            
2017  0.119303  
2018  0.137954  
2019  0.131544  
2020  0.130984
```

How do you normalize within the multiindex?

My expected output would be:

```
col1    A   A   B   B   C   C   D   D
col2    0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
Year                                
2017    0.478   0.522   0.495   0.505   0.528   0.472   0.491   0.509
2018    0.512   0.488   0.504   0.496   0.525   0.475   0.488   0.512
2019    0.520   0.480   0.540   0.460   0.454   0.546   0.466   0.534
2020    0.464   0.536   0.440   0.560   0.507   0.493   0.482   0.518
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `groupby().value_counts` with normalize:

```
#### Random data ####
np.random.seed(2)
Year = [2020,2019,2018,2017]*1000
col1 = np.repeat(['A','B','C','D'],1000)
col2 = np.random.randint(0,2,4000)

column_names = ['Year', 'col1', 'col2']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

df['Year'] = Year
df['col1'] = col1
df['col2'] = col2
#### End random data ####


(df.groupby(['Year','col1'])['col2']
   .value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack(['col1','col2'])
)
```

Output:

```
col1      A             B             C             D       
col2      0      1      1      0      0      1      1      0
Year                                                        
2017  0.524  0.476  0.528  0.472  0.540  0.460  0.512  0.488
2018  0.496  0.504  0.484  0.516  0.560  0.440  0.524  0.476
2019  0.496  0.504  0.552  0.448  0.484  0.516  0.508  0.492
2020  0.500  0.500  0.540  0.460  0.436  0.564  0.484  0.516
```

---

**Update**: For the weighted `value_counts`:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Year','col1','col2'])['weight'].sum()
new_df /= new_df.sum(level=['Year','col1'])
new_df = new_df.unstack(['col1','col2'])
```

Output:

```
col1         A                   B                   C                   D  \
col2         0         1         0         1         0         1         0   
Year                                                                         
2017  0.441176  0.558824  0.542500  0.457500  0.474286  0.525714  0.482857   
2018  0.500000  0.500000  0.474114  0.525886  0.481268  0.518732  0.489461   
2019  0.521622  0.478378  0.474490  0.525510  0.498801  0.501199  0.531343   
2020  0.493671  0.506329  0.479339  0.520661  0.515789  0.484211  0.513021   

col1            
col2         1  
Year            
2017  0.517143  
2018  0.510539  
2019  0.468657  
2020  0.486979
```

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry about that. So what if you use groupby and want to use weighted data which is simple with crosstabs with 'values' and 'aggfunc' paramter

Comment: in the code, `crosstab` uses `pivot_table`, which again is `groupby`. That's why if you know what to do, `groupby` is usually faster. In this case, you can also pass `normalize=True` to your `crosstab`. In the extended case, if you can provide a details, we can see how to pass `aggfunc` to `groupby`.